The pull-out faucet nozzle works only detached
I have a pull-out kitchen faucet. A few days ago I pulled the nozzle out to wash the sink. Afterward, the water runs with a very low pressure when the nozzle is attached to the faucet. However, when I pull the nozzle out water flows with a normal pressure. What's wrong? What should I do to resolve the issue?

Check the hose below the sink for pinches.  Maybe the weight that pulls it back down got dislodged.

Sounds like a kink in the hose indeed. Ideally a two person operation where one watches under the sink while another sprays the pulled out nozzle while slowly letting it back into the faucet, and the first looks for what is folded to block the flow when the flow suddenly reduces. Or it may be obvious by inspection if you know what you're looking for.

@Huesmann Thanks for your comments. You were right. I juts pulled the hose and adjusted the weight and now it is working as normal. Many thanks!

@Ecnerwal Thanks for your help and detailed explanation. I juts pulled the hose and adjusted the weight and now it is working as normal. Many thanks
